How to make question even clearer?
How can I make this question even clearer?

Is there any two-coordinate system where e.g., (10,36) is the same
point as (36,10)?
You see we here at the Rescue Centre are at our wits' end. Half our
reports come in with latitude first, half with longitude first. Yes, I
know about Plus Codes, but I am curious, has anybody ever fool proofed
a two coordinate system? Even for just plane coordinates?

The goofy Rescue Center part I cooked up to help clarify it, but it is still not clear enough to post.

Coordinates for what kind of points?  It is not clear what purpose is served by having $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ reference the same "point".  You might be interested in learning about quotient topologies.  Or you might not.  Adding a "goofy ... part [you] cooked up" adds to the confusion.

The goal is not at all clear.  You could, of course, just look at unordered pairs...but, in your fictional context, what would be the point?  What good would it do you to know that the latitude and longitude was ${a,b}$ in some order?  You'd still have to check two distinct physical points.

In any case, I don't think this is an appropriate question for this site.

Possible source of this question: Is there any two-coordinate system where X, Y is the same point as Y, X??

I don't find the requirements / problem statement clear.
It is not clear to me what "fool proofed" means.  Answerers need to know how possible answers will be evaluated (what are the requirements?), so they don't waste their time.  And readers need to know how to evaluate answers, so they can vote meaningfully.  The system requires a well-specified question, for the site to work well.
You can make it clearer by specifying more precisely what you are looking for.  You are looking for a coordinate system where $(x,y)$ denotes the same point as $(y,x)$.  Got it.  What other requirements do you have?  If I have a solution in mind, how would I tell whether it is satisfactory?  What are the criteria?  What solutions have you considered, and why have you rejected them?  Why is this interesting and relevant to others?  (Don't lie and claim it is relevant to rescue if that isn't actually based on your experience or evidence you have.)
I don't recommend adding fake, artificially invented pseudo-context (see also here and here).  That defeats the purpose of the site's requirement to provide context.

In fact, it is not even clear what OP means by a "coordinate system".
